# Regex to Replace Value Conditionally Only if Followed by a Number

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a regular expression that finds the opening parenthesis "(" and replaces it with a minus sign "-", but only if the parenthesis is followed by a number. How would I do that?

I came up with this code, but it doesn't leave the number in tact:

```
string1 = '(words) and (9878 )'

print(re.sub(r"\([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?", '-', string1))
```

That gives the result of:

```
'(words) and - )'
```

But I want this instead:

```
'(words) and -9878 )'
```

What do I need to change here so that I replace the '(' with '-', but don't eliminate the following number?

Comment: A lookahead: `r"\((?=[+-]?\d)"` in the regex will do.

Comment: That worked excellent. So in this case, is the "?=" the lookahead?

Comment: Yes, I explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with a simplified pattern in the regex itself:

```py
import re
string1 = '(words) and (9878 )'
print(re.sub(r"\((?=[+-]?\d)", '-', string1))
# => (words) and -9878 )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tklFb5) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PexZ4a/1).

A variation with a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```py
re.sub(r"\(([+-]?\d)", r'-\1', string1)
```

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?=[+-]?\d)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with an optional `+` or `-` and then any digit.

In this case, there is no need to check if there are more than one digits in the lookahead pattern, or if that number is followed with an optional `(?:\.\d+)?` pattern, only the obligatory prefix makes sense in this positive lookahead here.